# Spring doesn't instantiate bean at start

Tags: java, spring, maven

I'm stuck with the following problem. My application doesn't create my Services at startup and I end up with a `NullPointerException` when I try to use them in my Maven Tests after Inject them with `@Autowired`.

I don't understand where it comes from. I have done some research but I still don't understand why it doesn't work.

Here is the class where my Autowired `administrationActionService` is null:

```
public class AdministrationActionTests extends EntityTests {

    @Autowired
    AdministrationActionService administrationActionService;

    @Test
    public void equalsTests() {

        administrationActionService.getExample();

        [...]
```

The class :

```
package com.bloombooking.services;
@org.springframework.stereotype.Service
public class AdministrationActionService extends ServiceEntity{

    @Autowired private AdministrationActionDao administrationActionDao;

    [...]
```

And my `ApplicationContext.xml`. I've placed it in `src/ApplicationContext.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.bloombooking.services, com.bloombooking.dao"/>

</beans>
```

I really don't know what I could have done wrong. Can someone help me? Thanks!

Comment: How does `AdministrationActionTests` know where the application context file exists? What does `EntityTests` look like?

Comment: Hum ... What do you mean ? I need to make an link to the applicationContext file in AdministrationActionTests ? EntityTests is empty.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make it work you have to make the following changes:

1. add `@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)` to your class.
2. add `@ContextConfiguration("path_to_you_spring_beans.xml")`

So your class becomes:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration("path_to_you_spring_beans.xml")
AdministrationActionTests {
}
```

Comment: It work ! Thank you man ! Just a question : I have to add the @ContextConfiguration to all my files ? Or only for Maven Testing ?

Comment: you needs that in all test classes